# How Cakephp2.x connect Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, cakephp-2.0

I could not connect oracle with cakephp2, After search a few hour i found and followed [link](http://www.hassanbakar.com/2012/01/09/using-oracle-in-cakephp-2-0/)  step by step still not success, my oracle 11g

error:

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Answer (score 1):

I found solution with many errors, here what i fixed:
(Note still follow this [link](http://www.hassanbakar.com/2012/01/09/using-oracle-in-cakephp-2-0/comment-page-1/#comment-40324))

1. Error with php  version 5.4.+ ,p 5.3.0 (wamp server)
2. Error with oracle php file [file](http://snipt.org/uIgg5) with override function (method not compatible )
3. Error connect database config
4. Error SELECT * FROM your table name [don't use select * that will work]

How to fix:

1. If still php 5.3.0 enable module oci8
2. Use this [oracle file database](http://snipt.org/zKib2) i have been modified
3. in Cakephp Config database.php use

> ```
> public $dboracle = array(
>         'datasource' => 'Database/Oracle',
>         'driver' => 'oracle',
>         'connect' => 'oci_connect',
>         'persistent' => true,
>         'host' => "your host database ip",
>         'login' => 'db user name',
>         'password' => 'db password',
>         'database' => '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=you db ip )(PORT=1521))
>                     (CONNECT_DATA=(SID= you sid)))',
>         'prefix' => '',
>         'schema' => 'schema_name'
> );
> ```

Comment: Tried this method and so far I'm having trouble inserting new records, somehow my date field isn't validating (complains about null, but its in the request parameters). Any luck with that?

Comment: I have test only select related insert i am not yet test. Could you more detail how you insert?

Comment: Ok seems to be working fine now, the catch was that the SQL insert errors were not shown. Had to log the query string and see what the insert error was.

Answer (score 0):

First, the ORA error is a permutation of the ORA-12514: TNS listener cannot resolve service name error as shown below.  This form of the ORA-12541 error commonly happens when the database or the listener processes are in the middle of a startup, or when the database (mysid in your case) has not been registered with the listener.

root> oerr ora 12514

ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Cause:

- The listener received a request to establish a connection to a
  database or other service.
- The connect descriptor received by the listener specified a service
  name for a service (usually a database service) that either has not
  yet dynamically registered with the listener or has not been
  statically configured for the listener.
- This may be a temporary condition such as after the listener has
  started, but before the database instance has registered with the
  listener.

Action:

- Wait a moment and try to connect a second time.
- Check which services are currently known by the listener by
  executing: lsnrctl services
- Check that the SERVICE_NAME parameter in the connect descriptor of
  the net service name used specifies a service known by the listener.

If an easy connect naming connect identifier was used, check that the service name specified is a service known by the listener.

Check for an event in the listener.log file.

Comment: Thanks, I just found solution, oracle 11g need connect with connection string.